# Trying to add legend using geom_abline

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I have a data frame, saved as `df`, with two columns of points that I would like to plot. In addition, I would like to plot two lines on the plot and would like to have a legend for these lines. Here is my code:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y)) + 
  geom_point(color = "black", shape = 16, alpha = 1) +
  scale_x_continuous(name = "x", limits = c(-5, 5)) + 
  scale_y_continuous(name = "y", limits = c(-5, 5)) +
  geom_abline(intercept = 0, slope = 4/3, linetype = "dashed", 
              color = "gray40", size = 1, aes(colour = "XNULL")) + 
  geom_abline(intercept = 0, slope = 0, linetype = "dotted", 
              color = "gray40", size = 1, aes(colour = "YNULL")) +
  scale_color_manual(name = "", values = c("XNULL" = "red", "YNULL" = "blue")) +
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white"),
        panel.border = element_rect(colour = "black", fill = NA, size = 1),
        legend.position = "bottom")
```

However, when I run this, no legend comes up (I would like to have the legend on the bottom). Any suggestions as to what I am doing wrong? I am new at using `ggplot2`, and none of the solutions I looked up on other forums helped.

Answer (score 2):

You can try creating another data.frame to contain information about your ablines:

```
df = data.frame(x=runif(10),y=runif(10))
df2 = data.frame(intercept=0,slope=c(4/3,0),type=c("XNULL","YNULL"))
```

Then we can call `geom_abline` specifying the `aes` so that we can use

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y)) + 
geom_point(color = "black", shape = 16, alpha = 1) +
scale_x_continuous(name = "x", limits = c(-5, 5)) + 
scale_y_continuous(name = "y", limits = c(-5, 5)) +
geom_abline(data=df2,aes(intercept=intercept,slope=slope,
linetype=type,col=type),size = 1) +
scale_color_manual(name = "", values = c("XNULL" = "red", "YNULL" = "blue")) +
scale_linetype_manual(name = "", values = c("XNULL" = "dashed", "YNULL" = "dotted")) +
theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white"),
      panel.border = element_rect(colour = "black", fill = NA, size = 1),
legend.position = "bottom")
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

From the documentation:

> These geoms act slightly differently from other geoms. You can supply
>   the parameters in two ways: either as arguments to the layer function,
>   or via aesthetics. If you use arguments, e.g. geom_abline(intercept =
>   0, slope = 1), then behind the scenes the geom makes a new data frame
>   containing just the data you've supplied.

Apparently, you have to specify `intercept` and `slope` in `aes`, so that it works.

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width)) + 
  geom_point() +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(0,10), ylim = c(0,10)) +
  geom_abline(aes(intercept = 0, slope = 0, color = "X"), linetype = "dotted") +
  geom_abline(aes(intercept = 0, slope = 4/3, color = "Y"),linetype = "dashed") +
  scale_color_manual(values = c(X = 'grey', Y = 'black'))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-02-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Just to mention it, you can replace `geom_abline(aes(intercept = 0, slope = 0, color = "X")...)` by a `geom_hline(aes(yintercept = 0 ...` without the need for slope argument.